# Android Room DB - use static variable from another class in query

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

When I write a query in DAO class can I use a static variable from another class (or enum)? If it's possible, please tell me HOW?

I mean something like this:

```
public enum MessageState {
   NOTHING,
   PENDING,
   SEND
}
```

and in query statement in DAO class:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM message_db WHERE state = :MessageState.PENDING.ordinal()")
```

Comment: Have you tried the following way:

`@Query("SELECT * FROM message_db WHERE state = :msgState")

List<Messages> getMessageByState(MessageState msgState);`

Comment: @ankuranurag2 In actual my query is `@Query("SELECT * FROM message_db WHERE state = 1 OR state =2")` and in that way that you say I must always pass two `MessageState` that everywhere is constant. I think this is not the best way, But very thank you for reply

Answer (score 6):

Pass your enum to the function as a default parameter:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM message_db WHERE state = :state")
fun getMessages(state: Int = MessageState.PENDING.ordinal()): List<Message>
```

This way you won't need to provide it on every call, but achieve the same result.

Comment: This is good way in kotlin, but my project written with java. Is there somerhing like this way in java?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that. Perhaps in Java you could take advantage of method overloading and default interface methods introduced in Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate it just like a normal String, in Java:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM message_db WHERE state = " + MessageState.PENDING.ordinal() + ")"
```

If you are using Kotlin:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM message_db WHERE state = ${MessageState.PENDING.ordinal()}")
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me the error `Attribute value must be constant`

Comment: Do you need the `ordinal` method call? What happens if you remove it? (`MessageState.PENDING`)

Comment: Ok, I thought it wouldn't matter but it seems you can't use an `enum` in an `annotation`, they aren't constant at compile time so you should use a real compilation-time constant. Maybe you can find a workaround but I can't advice you in that.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply and hint.